# Template argument for std::vector initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, initialization

There is a struct called `Matrix` with a template argument `N` and `data_` field:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

template <std::size_t N>
struct Matrix {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data_{N, std::vector<int>(N)};
};
```

Why is it not possible to initialize `data_` using round brackets?

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data_(N, std::vector<int>(N));
```

Here's the error:

```
<source>:6:41: error: unknown type name 'N'
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data_(N, std::vector<int>(N));
                                        ^
<source>:6:61: error: declaration of 'N' shadows template parameter
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data_(N, std::vector<int>(N));
                                                            ^
<source>:4:23: note: template parameter is declared here
template <std::size_t N>
```

Comment: Because with round brackets this looks like a function declaration. That's literally why curly brackets were introduced for.

Comment: Afaik this is only true for class scope. If you try to do this in thr scope of a function it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) doesn't support parentheses initializer, but only braced initializer and equal-sign initializer.

> Through a *default member initializer*, which is a brace or equals [initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.

Beside the braced one you've showed, you can also

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct Matrix {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data_ = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(N, std::vector<int>(N));
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`()` has issue with regular declaration with most-vexing parse.

To avoid this possible issue, in class member initialization disallows that syntax.